# how to change position of image view in landscape mode

Tags: iphone

hi i am new to iphone. what i did is displaying grid of images,and a full image on image view. when ever i rotate the simulator to landscape left(or)right image view position is not changed. i need to change the postion and reduce the size of the image view in landscape mode how can i done this pls help me. post some code thank u .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set the image view position using following line

ImgHeading.frame  = CGRectMake(20, 25, 170, 42);

where ImgHeading is an imageView. The cgrectmake is consist of following coordinates

CGRectMake (x, y, Widht , height). now you can set the position according to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

`- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
    return YES;

}`
 Implement this method in your view controller.